# time(time_t *timer) gives wrong results without time drift in system

Tags: c, time, time.h

below code is for doing some stuff and sleep till next interval.
for calculation of sleep time, I am using below logic.

```
time_t start = time(0);
time_t end = time(0);
int timeLeft = 0;
int interval = 300;
while(1)
{

    /* do something
     * lets say takes 5 to 20 seconds to execute
     */
    end = time(0);
    timeLeft = interval -(end - start);
    printf("timeLeft: %d, interval: %d, end: %u, start: %u",timeLeft,interval,end,start);
    sleep(timeLeft)
    start = time(0);
}
```

After an uptime of 34 hours of the system, **timeLeft** is coming as greater than 300, which should never happen.
I have checked, there is no time drift in the system.

for an instance, when the issue happened,

> timeLeft: 11484, interval: 300, end: 1549402241, start: 1549413425

Don't know how can above happen?
need help.

Comment: why do you need to clock at start & end? just clock at start and use the new value as end.. (except for the last value)

Comment: Which OS and compiler? How are you monitoring `time_t`?

Comment: Can you show some values you’re seeing?

Comment: Does “end is coming as less and start is coming more comparatively” mean that sometimes `end` is less than `start`?

Comment: Please show how you are checking the values and what values you are seeing.

Comment: Updated actual question for the questions asked in comments.

Comment: uname -a
output on system

Linux 0005xxxxxxxxx 3.12.19-rt30 #1 SMP Thu Dec 20 17:55:58 IST 2018 ppc64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You didn't _show how you are checking the values_.

Comment: Added. Above is a simplified version of the actual code. Can't post actual code

Comment: It should happen, you are not using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Comment: These probably aren't the specific answer but two things you should so are 1) use the correct format specifier for `start` and `end`. On my computer, it's `%ld` and 2) have a check that `end - start` does not exceed 300, otherwise you'll be sleeping with a negative `timeleft`.

Answer (score 0):

This analysis of the issue doesn't actually give a single answer, but it was too long to fit in a comment so here goes.

After looking at your code, it appears that the problem is that **end < start**. But **end = time(0)** is always called after **start = time(0)**.

Your example assumes that you can subtract **time_t** values and get the elapsed seconds between them, but the C standard does not guarantee that. Your code seems to be running on a recent version of Linux so I took a look at the [GNU Libc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Calendar-Time.html#Simple-Calendar-Time), and apparently **time** returns the number of secs since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970, and a time_t is a long int. I also checked the values of **start** and **end**, when the issue occurred, and their values are about 49 years worth of secs, and since it been 49 years since January 1, 1970, it appears that the assumption in your example is valid.

My best guess is that there is some significant difference between the actual code and your example. Perhaps a call to **start = time(0)** that takes place after the call to **end=time(0)**, or maybe situations where a call to end=time(0) does not take place.

You can rule this out by converting your example into an actual program and see if that program has the same issue. If it does, you can post the code for the program. This site encourages people to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In the meantime, I can make some other guesses:

1. Your program has more than one thread, and your threads are stepping on each other.
2. Some weird compiler optimization is causing the calls to **time(0)** to be moved around.